# What happened to no indexing certain directories?

Tags: unity, unity-dash

Ubuntu 13.04 no longer has an option to keep certain folders from being indexed. Why was this removed and how do you reinstate it?

Comment: Very good question, considering that having some very large folders in your home directory can completely break the Unity dash search at times: https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/1175443

Answer (score 2):

You can customize the index locations/folders using [tracker-gui [image: Install tracker-gui]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/tracker-gui).

Install it with this button:

[image: Install via the software center]

or using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install tracker-gui
```

After installing, go to the Locations tab. Click on the + button and add the specific directories/locations that you want to index.

It goes without saying that the drive has to be mounted already to be able to be indexed.
Hope that helps.

[image]

Or You can go here and add to "don't record activity":

[image]

Or else, You can also do the following : Install activity-log-manager

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:zeitgeist/ppa
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install activity-log-manager
```

You can then launch it by searching for it in Unity. Once it's loaded, you'll find the option to prevent certain folders being logged in the Files tab. Hope that helps.

Comment: AFAIK, Unity doesn't use tracker.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround, which concerns indexing in apache:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/enabling-apache-file-directory-indexing/

Main thing is to add some code with editor in conf-file like it is done here in conf-file of apache (this code-snippet is an example) :

```
> <Directory /var/www/domain.com/pdfs> Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
> </Directory>
```

Comment: OM, does that solve yr problem? 73s...

Comment: would be -Indexes to stop them from being indexed for that example but what does the OP want to avoid being indexed by?

Comment: This question is about Unity, not Apache.

Comment: yes OMDG - true - but thought this only as example, how to solve the intention of indexing (here with apache). you could modify it slightly for the purpose above needed. Is there no conf-file of unity ?!